# how can set headers (user-agent), retrieve a web page, capture redirects and accept cookies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
import urllib.request
url="http://espn.com"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
contents = f.read().decode('latin-1')
q = f.geturl()
print(q)
```

This code will return `http://espn.go.com/`, which is what I want -- a redirect web site URL.  After looking at the Python documentation, googling, etc., I can't figure out how to also:

1. Capture redirected web site URL (already working)
2. Change the user-agent on the out going request
3. Accept any cookies the web page might want to send back

How can I do this in Python 3?  If there is a better module than `urllib`, I am OK with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* a better module, it's called [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/):

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'My-requests-agent/0.1'

resp = session.get(url)
contents = resp.text  # If the server said it's latin 1, this'll be unicode (ready decoded)
print(resp.url)       # final URL, after redirects.
```

`requests` follows redirects (check `resp.history` to see what redirects it followed). By using a session (optional), cookies are stored and passed on to subsequent requests. You can set headers *per request* or *per session* (so the same extra headers will be sent with every request sent out for that session).

Answer (score 7):

A simple demo using urllib (python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os.path
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar,MozillaCookieJar

cj = MozillaCookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

cookie_file=os.path.abspath('./cookies.txt')

def load_cookies(cj,cookie_file):
    cj.load(cookie_file)
def save_cookies(cj,cookie_file):
    cj.save(cookie_file,ignore_discard=True,ignore_expires=True)

def dorequest(url,cj=None,data=None,timeout=10,encoding='UTF-8'):
    data = urlencode(data).encode(encoding) if data else None

    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data,timeout=timeout)
    return f.read()

def dopost(url,cj=None,data=None,timeout=10,encoding='UTF-8'):
    body = dorequest(url,cj,data,timeout,encoding)
    return body.decode(encoding)
```

You should check the headers if redirecting happening(30x).

Comment: +1 Thanks, this did the trick.  I liked this solution the best.

Comment: I needed a solution using urllib/http and not requests and this solution got me there